# JavaScript: this.files[0].name in IE: Unable to get property 'name' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using:

```
if($(this).length > 0){
    alert(this.files[0].name);
}
```

The JS is in this HTML:

```
<input type="file" onchange="{JS_FROM_ABOVE}">
```

Works fine in Chrome but in IE I get:

```
Unable to get property 'name' of undefined or null reference
```

Any advice or workaround?

Comment: Could you provide the HTML part? Also, please add linebreaks to the javascript to make it more readable

Comment: Amended now .....

Comment: No, we need the HTML for which you execute jQuery on.

Comment: Note that `$(this).length` will always be 1. You should be checking `this.files.length` to ensure there are files chosen.

Comment: @Neskews not sure what else you want - there is a file input that has an onChange on it

Comment: I see a `.next('span')`. I would expect you have at least `<span></span>` in your HTML.

Comment: That's not the issue - the error is happening on this.files[0].name - is there another way around this? Have amended so it doesn't have any span so we can just concentrate on the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I try to test your sample code with the IE 11 browser and found that it is working fine.

Tested code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" onchange="if($(this).length > 0){
    alert(this.files[0].name);}">
</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11 browser:

[image]

I suggest trying to run my above test code on your side to check for the result. See if it works for you.

If the issue persists then please inform us which version of the IE browser you are using for making this test? Let us know which version of the JQuery you are using for making this test. It may help to narrow down the issue.